# Get dynamic content from custom notification in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble receiving notification content
when i pressing a button in the Custom Notification runs a BroadcastReceiver.
And these codes are executed inside the receiver.
I want the real time content from textview.

```
public class IntentBtnSpeaker extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_push, null);
            TextView txtMean = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMean);
            Toast.makeText(context, txtMean.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to put that content data on the `Intent` backing the click `PendingIntent` you're setting on the `Notification`'s `RemoteViews`, and retrieve from the `Intent` passed into `onReceive()` in your `BroadcastReceiver`. Inflating the layout anew is just going to give you the `View`s and attribute values as they're defined in the XML.

Comment: The intent only has the current time content and if multiple notifications are sent, previous notifications can not use the content of the intent.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. "The intent only has the current time content" – That's kinda what I gathered you wanted. "if multiple notifications are sent, previous notifications can not use the content of the intent." – If you have multiple `Notification`s active simultaneously, you should be creating unique `PendingIntent`s for each. You can do so by passing a unique request code as the second argument in `getBroadcast()`. You could just use the same value that you're using for each `Notification`'s ID.

Comment: If, instead, you mean that you only have one `Notification`, and it's just not updating that content with each new `notify()`, then pass an appropriate flag as the fourth argument in `getBroadcast()`; e.g., `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I have have multiple **Notifications** active simultaneously.

Comment: Ah, OK. Did that work for you, then? Was I clear enough in my description?

Comment: Please give an example as a post answer to get a particular intent in the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191312/discussion-between-hamid-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0):

Make **IntentBtnSpeaker** as a inner class of Particular activity. then you can directly get the required **Textview** data access.

Comment: If the class is not a type of receiver, how will the click event be received?